# Product metric spaces is again a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, self-learning

Let $(X,d_X)$ and $(Y,d_Y)$ be metric spaces, and let:
$$
d_2 ((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)) = \left[d_X(x_1,x_2)^2 + d_Y (y_1,y_2)^2 \right]^{\frac{1}{2}}
$$
for the points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ in $X \times Y$. I would like to show that the triangle inequality holds, that is:
$$
d_2 ((x_1,y_1),(x_3,y_3))  \leq d_2 ((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)) + d_2 ((x_2,y_2),(x_3,y_3)) \tag{1}
$$
but I'm really stuck.

---

**What I have tried so far:**

Since $d_X$ and $d_Y$ are by definition metrics, we can use the triangle inequality to write:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
d_2 ((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)) & + d_2 ((x_2,y_2),(x_3,y_3)) \\& 
= \left[d_X(x_1,x_2)^2 + d_Y(y_1,y_2)^2 \right]^{\frac{1}{2}} + \left[d_X(x_2,x_3)^2 + d_Y(y_2,y_3)^2 \right]^{\frac{1}{2}} \\&
\leq \left[[d_X(x_1,x_3)+d_X(x_3,x_2)]^2 + [d_Y(y_1,y_3)+d_Y(y_3,y_2)]^2 \right]^{\frac{1}{2}} \\&
+ \left[[d_X(x_2,x_1)+d_X(x_1,x_3)]^2 + [d_Y(y_2,y_1)+d_Y(y_1,y_3)]^2 \right]^{\frac{1}{2}}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $(x_3,y_3) \in X \times Y$, and we know that:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
d_2 ((x_1,y_1),(x_3,y_3)) = \left[ d_X(x_1,x_3)^2 + d_Y(y_1,y_3)^2 \right]^{\frac{1}{2}} 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Then, substituting the above two equations into equation $(1)$ yields:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\Bigl[ d_X(x_1,x_3)^2 & + d_Y(y_1,y_3)^2 \Bigr]^{\frac{1}{2}}  \\&
\leq \left[[d_X(x_1,x_3)+d_X(x_3,x_2)]^2 + [d_Y(y_1,y_3)+d_Y(y_3,y_2)]^2 \right]^{\frac{1}{2}} \\&
+ \left[[d_X(x_2,x_1)+d_X(x_1,x_3)]^2 + [d_Y(y_2,y_1)+d_Y(y_1,y_3)]^2 \right]^{\frac{1}{2}}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
I'm not really sure how to proceed from here onwards (or perhaps I'm already on the wrong track), and any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you are on the wrong track. Instead of using algebra, try geometry, namely, use Pythagorean theorem in the plane and the fact that the Euclidean metric on the plane is a metric.

Comment: @studiosus I'm not sure I understand your hint. I would like to show it for general sets $X$ and $Y$, and *not* restricting myself to $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$. Are we then still allowed to use Pythagorean theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to prove:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}d_X(x_1,x_3)^2+d_Y(y_1,y_3)^2 &\leq& d_X(x_1,x_2)^2+d_X(x_2,x_3)^2+d_Y(y_1,y_2)^2+d_Y(y_2,y_3)^2\\&+&2\sqrt{\left(d_X(x_1,x_2)^2+d_Y(y_1,y_2)^2\right)\left(d_X(x_2,x_3)^2+d_Y(y_2,y_3)^2\right)}\end{eqnarray*}$$
where the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality ensures that the last square root is greater or equal than:
$$ d_X(x_1,x_2)\,d_X(x_2,x_3)+d_Y(y_1,y_2)\,d_Y(y_2,y_3)$$
hence it is sufficient to show that:
$$d_X(x_1,x_3)^2+d_Y(y_1,y_3)^2\leq\left(d_X(x_1,x_2)+d_X(x_2,x_3)\right)^2+\left(d_Y(y_1,y_2)+d_Y(y_2,y_3)\right)^2$$
that just follows from the triangle inequality for $d_X$ and $d_Y$.

Comment: What a nice proof, thanks! Small suggestion: I think in the first equation on the LHS $d_Y(x_1,x_3)$ should be $d_Y(y_1,y_3)$.

Comment: @Hunter: you are right, updated.

Comment: Sir, can we direct apply just Minkowski inequality for real numbers on $d_2((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2))$ ? Because $d_X(x_1,x_2), d_Y(y_1,y_2)$ are distances and hence by definition of metric they are positive real numbers. So that triangle inequality for $d_2$ is directly follows from Minkowski inequality. Sir please reply...

Answer (score 1):

Here is the geometric argument I alluded to:

Suppose you have a triple of points
$$
z_1=(x_1, y_1), z_2=(x_2, y_2), z_3=(x_3, y_3)\in X\times Y.
$$
Then both triples of distances 
$$
d(x_i, x_j), 1\le i\ne j\le 3; d(y_i, y_j), 1\le i\ne j\le 3
$$
satisfy triangle inequalities. Therefore, we can realize them by triangles $\Delta(x_1', x_2', x_3'), \Delta(y_1', y_2', y_3')$ in the Euclidean plane $E^2$.

Now, define the triangle $\Delta'=\Delta(z_1', z_2', z_3')\subset E^2\times E^2=E^4$ whose vertices project to the vertices of the triangles $\Delta(x_1', x_2', x_3'), \Delta(y_1', y_2', y_3')$. By the definition of the product metric on $X\times Y$ and the Pythagorean formula, the side-lengths of the triangle $\Delta'$ are the same as $d(z_1, z_2), d(z_2, z_3), d(z_3, z_1)$. Since $E^4$ is a metric space, the distances $d(z_1, z_2), d(z_2, z_3), d(z_3, z_1)$ satisfy the triangle inequalities.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is very nice to see the geometric interpretation of product spaces!