# Is triangle inequality for product space can follow from Minkowski inequality?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Below question is asked so many times, just like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/931139/168676) but I need to know that can we prove triangle inequality by using Minkowski inequality for sum.

> **Question**: let $X=X_1\times X_2$ be Cartesian product of two metric spaces $(X_1,d_1)$ and $(X_2,d_2)$. Is the function $d$ defined by
>
> $d(x,y)=\sqrt{d_1(x_1,y_1)^2+d_2(x_2,y_2)^2}$ is metric on $X$?

**My attempt**:  we need to prove,

$d(x,y)≤d(x,z)+d(z,y)$

i.e. $\sqrt{d_1(x_1,y_1)^2+d_2(x_2,y_2)^2}≤ \sqrt{d_1(x_1,z_1)^2+d_2(x_2,z_2)^2} +\sqrt{d_1(z_1,y_1)^2+d_2(z_2,y_2)^2}$

Which follows directly from Minkowski's inequality for sum. Because,

$d_1(x_1,y_1),d_1(x_2,y_2),d_1(x_1,z_1)d_1(x_2,y_2),d_1(z_1,y_1),d_2(z_2,y_2)$ are **positive** real numbers.

**is am i correct?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first apply triangle in equality for $d_1$ and $d_2$ and then use Minkowski's inequality.

Comment: Sir, thanks for the answer. ( Yes I forget to write after applying triangle inequality for $d_1$, $d_2$)

Comment: Sir, I am still facing the problem :-(

Comment: Consider the vectors $(d_1(x_1,z_1),d_2(x_2,z_2)$ and $(d_1(z_1,y_1),d_2(z_2,y_2)$. If these are $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ then $\|(a,b)+(c,d)\| \leq \|(a,b)\|+\|(c,d\|$ where $\|.\|$ denotes the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb R^{2}$. This gives the answer immediately.